# is there a difference in two if statements in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

is there a difference between:

```
 if (myObject != null && myObject.someint == 0)
 {
      // do something
 }
```

and

```
if (myObject != null)
{
    if (myObject.someint == 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I always thought that it evaluates the first condition, and if false, it skips evaluation of the second. However I got an error in run-time of null-reference. `myObject` was null, and it was trying to check `myObject.someint`

The object can be modified externally, is it a case when it checked the first condition the object existed, but when it went on to the next condition something has killed the reference in myObject?

if its the latter, any way to avoid (b/c in my mind both of the above ways of doing the if check are the same). only possible i can imagine is `try/catch`

Comment: The better way to avoid: don't modify the object externally without locking.  If you can describe a way that `myObject` could be set to null during the execution of either if statement, you have a race condition, plain and simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be the later condition since the && short circuits on `false`. Use

```
lock(myObject)
```

Comment: Agreed you have multithreading issues. Need to lock around your access to myObject

Answer (score 3):

`C#` uses short-circuit evaluation, so they are equivalent.

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary. [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

But as @pst points out, it's likely to be a threading issue.

Comment: +1 ...and both equally broken if "externally modified" means multi-threading... although it would be interesting to see if one of the IL generations was "more resilient" to these cases.

Answer (score -3):

The first one will check for the 2 conditions and it might throw an exception in the second condition `myObject.someint` = 0 if the first condition was `Null`..

The second one will first check if the object is not `Null` then proceed to the next check, otherwise it will not continue. in this case there won't be any exception thrown..

so basically, I'd select the second one. it will not throw an exception and I don't need to use `try/catch` thingy...

Comment: -1, both snippets are equivalent as they are written. The `&&` operator short-circuits, meaning that if the first condition evaluates to false then the second condition is not evaluated. They are NOT necessarily both evaluated, as you described.